# How to add a tar files in git repository?

Tags: git, github, tar

I have added couple of tar bundles in my source code under directory misc_files. These tar files is added to test certain functionalities and would be only used by test suite.

Now my problem is that when I am doing `git status` I cannot see the misc_files directory, probably because it does not contain any such files that can be recognized by git.
I wanted to add this new directory **misc_files** containing tar bundles into the git repo, what should I do?

Comment: Git doesn't care about file types, most likely you have *.tar in your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: You're probably using Octocat's global git ignore file. Just `git add misc_files/filename.tar -f` to force add it.

Answer (score 1):

Hey，Bhupesh Pant，I wanna add a comment to your question, but now I can not.

so, try out:

```
git add misc_files
```

then, try `git status` again.

Comment: Hi, Can you please add more details into this.

Comment: According to your commnet,  when you are running `git add misc_files`, you are adding `misc_files` to your git repo to track, usually, it will have no output. Then, running `git status`, git will tell you what files it is tracking now.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, there is no filetypes, that are not 'recognized' by git. git just ignores empty folders. So if you added a folder, which is empty, you won't see it in `git status`. But, in your case, *.tar files are there. It can mean that they are ignored in `.gitignore`. Check it out. If that's true, just remove `*.tar` from `.gitignore`.

**Upd**
Just tried again. For me it works as expected. If I add new folder (misc_files) with no files, I don't see it in `git status`. If I add .tar file there, I see, that folder is untracked:
[image]

Anyway, what you can try, is to run `git add misc_files -f` - it adds all files to staging area, even files which are normally ignored. Could you run it and see what happens?

Comment: Exactly, this is what I know but in my case this is not happening. I have got no entries in .gitignore file for *.tar. Still I am not able to see newly added tar files under misc_files.